# TYPO3. How to overwrite class in Indexed Search extension

Tags: replace, typo3, overwrite

I want to overwrite class IndexedSearchUtility by my own class IndexedSearchUtility which is located in my site-package.
I tried this in my code.

In ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\Utility\\IndexedSearchUtility'] = ['IndexedSearchUtility' => 'EXT:my_site_package/Classes/Utility/IndexedSearchUtility'];
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\Utility\\IndexedSearchUtility'] = [
'IndexedSearchUtility' => 'MyVendor\\MySitePackage\\Utility\\IndexedSearchUtility'];
```

In IndexedSearchUtility.php

```
class IndexedSearchUtility extends TYPO3\CMS\IndexedSearch\Utility\IndexedSearchUtility
{ 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedSearchUtility contains only static methods, XCASS'ing static methods does not work.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html

You'd have to override (non-static) callers if necessary.